# HTTP header to return server available content types

Tags: rest, http, content-negotiation

E.g. Suppose we have a restful API endpoint to return orders, that can output in different formats.

```
[GET] /orders/42
```

that could return xml, json or pdf.

I thought that the best option, in a restful paradigm, could have been to return available types as an header in the relative OPTION call:

```
[OPTION] /tests
```

But I do not know if there exists something like a content negotiation server header to list available content types.

I suppose that it should look something like:

```
Available-Content-Types: application/xml,application/json,application/pdf
```

Does something similar exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) works the other way around.

The client makes a request for the resource (typically using GET) and includes an `Accept` header with a list of acceptable `Content-Type`s (using a quality value to describe the preference order).

The server then determines which response to send based on that.

So a client might send:

```
Accept: application/json;q=1, application/xml;q=0.9, application/pdf;0.5, */*;q-0.1
```

Then the server would determine what type of data to return. Assuming all formats were equally good in the server's eyes, it would return JSON because that had the highest quality value from the client.

Answer (score 1):

> Does something similar exists?

No.

[Content Negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4) is specified in two flavors.

[Proactive negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.1) involves encoding the user agent's preferences into the initial request (using [headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3); for example: [Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)).  The server chooses a suitable representation for the response.

[Reactive negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.2) is closer to what you are looking for -- the user agent choosing a resource based on information provided by the server.

[300 Multiple Choices](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.1) signals to the client that alternative representations are available.

> The 300 (Multiple Choices) status code indicates that the target resource has more than one representation, each with its own more specific identifier, and information about the alternatives is being provided so that the user (or user agent) can select a preferred
> representation by redirecting its request to one or more of those identifiers.

The `Location` header is used to identify which of the alternatives is the servers preferred reference, but there is no standard for enumerating the other alternatives.

> For request methods other than HEAD, the server SHOULD generate a payload in the 300 response containing a list of representation metadata and URI reference(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most preferred.  The user agent MAY make a selection from that list automatically if it understands the provided media type.

On the web, this would probably look like a web page with a list of links encoded into it.  The browser would render the list, and the user could choose whatever was appropriate.  The servers preferred choice would *also* be described in the Location header, and the user agent could simply re-direct to that preferred alternative without first consulting the user.

If there were a header that could do this work, you would find it in the [IANA header registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml); I don't see anything that looks like a match, so it's media-type or nothing.